# Dask Intermediate Results

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a smallish Dask custom application (~20 nodes in the DAG). I would like to be able to somehow persist all of the intermediate results of the functions for future inspection, as sometimes we want to know why we reached our final answer. Are there any good patterns for this within Dask other than pushing the results to Redis (or the like) just before returning the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute intermediate results along with your final results.

```
a = dask.delayed(inc)(1)
b = dask.delayed(inc)(2)
c = dask.delayed(add)(a, b)

dask.compute(c)  # only return c, releasing a and b as soon as possible

dask.compute(a, b, c)  # return all three
```

Comment: Will dask keep the intermediate results from c to return a and b? Or will it compute a, b, and, c independently, duplicating computation for a & b?

Comment: It will do the intelligent thing, merge all task graphs together, execute that graph, and return the desired outputs.